# How to find where the exception was thrown inside a BackgroundWorker thread?

Tags: c#, exception, backgroundworker

Ok, this should be basic, but I was unable to find a good answer.
I just want to VS breaks at the exception thrown inside the BackgroundWorker.
Code sample:

```
    private void btnBGWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_DoWork;
        bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //I know e.Error have the Exception but
        if (e.Error != null)
            throw e.Error; //Well this does not work, VS will throw TargetInvocationException
    }

    void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //** How can I make VS break here !!!??? **
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the "Debug > "Exceptions" menu, then make sure there is a check mark in the "Thrown" column next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".  That will make Visual Studio break on all exceptions that are thrown from your CLR code.